Where is command palette Visual Studio 2022
I am looking for command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) in VS 2022. Ctrl + Shift + P is doing nothing. But I can't find it. I need it to toggle Activity Bar Visibility chat because one person on SO says

Open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and type Keyboard Shortcuts.

Click on Toggle Activity Bar Visibility, and choose your shortcut using the keyboard!

It's done!


Tried to search in Options window.

"one person on SO says"... Are you sure they aren't referring to Visual Studio Code?
